# As Moira, can you cancel your own ultimate ability?

Tags: overwatch

When playing as Moira, her ultimate ability (Coalescence) lasts for quite some time.  Normally, this would be a good thing.

However, you make for an easy target for certain enemy ultimate abilities, such as D.Va's Self-Destruct, as you can't use your Fade ability during Coalescence.

Is there any way to end Coalescence early?

Answer (score 14):

No you can't cancel your own ultimate, apart from killing yourself.

Enemies such as McCree and Hog can cancel the ult when using some of their abilities on you, but Moira can't do it alone.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to permaturely cancel Coalescence as Moira. It will only stop at the end of the ultimate's duration.

That said, Coalescence has a range of 30 meters and grants Moira a noticeable speed boost, which makes it easier to stay out of harm's way and retreat behind a corner in case of a Self-Destruct or Deadeye.

Comment: While I mentioned D.Va by name, Junkrat's tire is actually the biggest thorn in my side while I'm ulting as you can't really dodge it due to its high speed, plus Coalescence doesn't do as much damage to it as you might think it should.  Normally, as Moira, a properly timed Fade can save you from a Junkirate Tire... I have something like an 80%+ dodge rate on said tires with her.